# what is the minimum time Order of a query in SQL databases?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sqlite, database-optimization

I want to know what is the minimum query time in a given `SQL`(specially `SQLite`) database(with n records).
I know that `full table scan` is `O(n)` and for indexed column (and `RowId`) it is `O(log(n))`.

1st question : is there any situation that the time is smaller than `O(log(n))`?

2nd question : why querying on `RowId` (`SELECT *FROM table_01 WHERE rowid='234'`)is also O(log(n))?? if it (`RowId`)is ordered from 1 to n I **logically** expect that `SQL` can **immediately** find the row with a given `RowId`

Comment: For 2nd question, please answer this simple question: you have a book that have 2000 pages. Now you want go to page 1077. How could you find that page **immediately**? And one more level, if the page is not 1, 2, 3,... but 1, 3, 15, 17 (lost many pages)?

Comment: computer is not a person! it can jump to the location!

Comment: when computer wants to read a memory address for example 0xt543s4ff32 it does not search for it!!!

Comment: Sorry, i'm wrong. `rowid is address of the row` so for your query in 2nd question, database should immediately find that row. Which source do you get that it is O(log(n))? You should check query plan to confirm that.

Comment: This is query plan for oracle `1 - TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID - access(CHARTOROWID('2392'))` `0 - SELECT STATEMENT`. No scan, immediately access. I expected the same or similar plan for `SQLite`.

Comment: this source --->https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Comment: from the sorce : "One technique for avoiding a full table scan is to do lookups by rowid (or by the equivalent INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)...Since the information is stored in the table in rowid order, SQLite can find the correct row using a binary search. If the table contains N element, the time required to look up the desired row is proportional to logN rather than being proportional to N as in a full table scan."

Comment: It seems that with `SQLite`, rowid is not physical address of the row in hard disk (because of its design to be a moveable database). It's only logical address so that `SQLite` could search for row that store in its `B-tree` structure, as in its document. So, not like MSSQL or Oracle, postgre...., `SQLite` could, and should not create a list of physical addess (rowid in other RDBMS) so that it could directly access each row. And then it create list of `logical address`, that special rowid. For more about this, you should ask in `https://dba.stackexchange.com/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding a specific row requires a search. (Not every rowid is necessarily present, so the database needs to look.) The optimistic case, or even the average case, should be much faster than log(n), but the worst case cannot be, since it requires searching a list.

Comment: lets suppose all rowid is present(1 to n) and we want m-th row , so we know exactly where it is, so no need for search only get it!

Comment: No, it cannot. Computers need to index the locations of items so they can look them up - it's not "add M to the position of item 1".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the smallest or largest value from an indexed column (`SELECT MIN(x) FROM table`), the database [can simply read the first or last value](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#minmax), and the time is in O(1).

Indexes are stored as a B-tree, with the indexed columns as the key.
Tables are stored as a B-tree, with the `rowid` as the key, so searching for the `rowid` is just as fast as searching for a value in an index.

Comment: as  Pham X. Bach said (if correct!)accessing by rowid in Oracle , MySql ..(NOT SQLite) is also O(1)